# Initialize a ServiceClient see error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' to 'System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler'"

Tags: c#, rest

```
public partial class MyServiceClient : ServiceClient<MyServiceClient>, IMyServiceClient
{

    public MyServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient, bool disposed) : base(httpClient, disposed)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
 }
```

I see this error message below. Can you give some advice?

```
client2 = new MyServiceClient(new HttpClient(), false);

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' to 'System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where's the rest of your partial class?

Comment: Seems you need to not just call `new HttpClient()`, but first need to make an instance of `HttpClientHandler`, use that to create a new `HttpClient`, then pass the _handler_ into your constructor for MyServiceClient.  See MSDN for [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1) and for the constructors to [ServiceClient<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.serviceclient-1.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet)